# Are there any year round beaches with nearby bouldering?

Tags: climbing, rock-climbing, beach, bouldering

I want it all in one.  I recently went to Florida and fell in love with West Palm Beach, but I could never live there due to the lack of climbing.

Are there any locations which combine year round warmth, Florida Key style sand beaches, and readily available spots suitable for someone experienced in bouldering?

Answer (score 7):

If you are into sport climbing, Thailand has got to be the place.  Specifically, check out Krabi or Railay, also anywhere that offers deep water soloing.

The downside to Thailand is that you'll spend half the year looking for rock that isn't wet (i.e. during rainy season).